# Молочные реки и кисельные берега

Tags: фразеология

Всегда несколько озадачивал этот фразеологизм (специалисты, извините, если неправильно употребила термин) в значении изобилия и достатка. Ладно еще молочные реки, но почему берега-то кисельные?)) Это ж форменная топь получается)))

Answer (score 1):

Кисельные берега - это не берега из киселя, а берега, заросшие тем, из чего можно варить кисель.

Варианты такие: А) Кисель варили из овса, картофельного крахмала. Б)В Тверской области есть река Молога - она же молочная. Берега её называют кисельными, так как они густо заросли дикой лесной смородиной, из которой местное население варит кисель.